# Channel Form elements not populating entry

Tags: channel-form

I have some checkbox entry fields and select option fields that are not populating my channel entry through my channel form. All the other input fields, including a standard select dropdown, populate fields correctly.  I am using REEgion to add the states/provinces and I have radio buttons trying to select the checkboxes.

Below is a sample of my templates:

**Checkboxes:**

```
<div class="row narrow-width">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Do you require a deposit?:</legend>
                <label for="require_deposit1"><input type="radio" value="yes" name="require_deposit" id="require_deposit1"> Yes</label><br>
                <label for="require_deposit2"><input type="radio" value="no" name="require_deposit" id="require_deposit2"> No</label><br>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
```

The ID's and NAME elements all match the custom field tags.  Thanks for any help you can offer.

**Select dropdown:**

```
<div class="row narrow-width">
            <label for="bank_state_province">Bank State/Province: </label>
            {exp:reegion_select:states_provinces title="State or Province" id="bank_state_province" name="bank_state_province" class="reegion_select"}
        </div>
```

Comment: did you try to create this fields using {field:my_field_name} tag? What happens in this case?

Comment: I get the same issue.  I tried that one before but it wasn't populating the checkboxes either and the REEgion fields have not worked at all.

Comment: is this form available online?